# How to read a port by a label in Mplab Harmony?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx, mplab-harmony

I'm more familiarized with MCC and with that framework is really easy to read a port we just need to give a `custom name` in `pin module`:

[image]

and after that in code:

DATA_IN_GetValue()

My question is how the same can be done in the Harmony framework because the label/name matters to me. I know we can read the ports with the overcomplicated function it has, but is there a way using the names?

I gave a name to the port here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the port a name and a function and generate code... example...

[image]

You'll noticed that in `system_config.h` harmony **only** creates the following

```
/*** Functions for MY_TEST_PIN pin ***/
#define MY_TEST_PIN_PORT PORT_CHANNEL_E
#define MY_TEST_PIN_PIN PORTS_BIT_POS_6
#define MY_TEST_PIN_PIN_MASK (0x1 << 6)
```

which can be used as your parameters for `PLIB_PORTS_PinGet`, i.e.

`PLIB_PORTS_PinGet (PORTS_ID_0, MY_TEST_PIN_PORT, MY_TEST_PIN_PIN)`

You should probably define that in your application `app.h` to make it simpler

`#define GET_MY_TEST_PIN() PLIB_PORTS_PinGet (PORTS_ID_0, MY_TEST_PIN_PORT, MY_TEST_PIN_PIN)`

then somewhere where you want to get the pin value...

```
unsigned char MY_TEST_PIN_VALUE = GET_MY_TEST_PIN();
```

Comment: This is what i was looking. I searched for "DATA_IN" and no result was found. Its clear now why... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
#define   DATA_IN   RE6

value = DATA_IN;
```

otherwise you could use this with harmony:

```
PLIB_PORTS_PinGet (PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_E, PORTS_BIT_POS_6)
```

or

```
PLIB_PORTS_PinGet (PORTS_ID_0, PORT_CHANNEL_E, DATA_IN)
```

but I guess it's much more complicated.

Comment: Hi @Mike, you mean ```PORTEbits.RE6```? In ```Pin Settings``` of Harmony, i define the name ```DATA_IN``` but is it not used anywhere? what's the point of defining that name then (in pin settings)? I can manually do the define in the code, but was hoping harmony did some kind of define for me.